# how to install latex, nedit and xdvi packages in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, software-installation, latex, tools

I'm trying  to install one tool in Ubuntu and in order to run the tool,the following packages must be installed : nedit, latex and xdvi.I'm using ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
Anyone can suggest the way to do all these 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install texlive-full nedit
```

That should do the trick.

I believe `xdvi` comes with `texlive`, so you should be good to go.

Comment: I tried sudo apt-get install texlive-full texmaker,I found it from web only. Nedit come along with it? Is it a right command?

Comment: The following text is the description about the installation of that tool"Compilation requires make to be available, and in order to run the tool we also assume nedit, latex and xdvi to be installed What are the things I have to do for this?

Comment: `nedit` must be installed separately, so do `sudo apt-get install nedit`.
What exactly are you trying to install?

Comment: I'm trying to install one tool "clawcircus" from circus family.Do you know how to install it?Can you check and tell me what I need to install for that one?

Comment: I assume you're talking about [this](https://www.cs.york.ac.uk/circus/tools/control.php)? 
Well, their documentation is *awful*.
What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sir I downloaded the binary version from the site and tried to install it in ubuntu 14.04 LTS.But it didn't work.So again I installed the packages which I mentioned last day.Again I tried to install it,the same problems happened.I don't have an idea about how to install it now

Comment: What error message are you getting? Maybe we can continue this on another question?

Comment: When I try to install it,I can't find any configuration files to install.

Comment: 1. Download clawcircus-src.tar.gz and extract it.
2. Go inside the directory and type in 'sudo make'.

That should compile all the .jar files for you.

Comment: All the programs you probably need are in the 'bin' folder. Navigate there using the terminal and check them out. 

I'm not too sure what this program does, so I'm sorry I can't be very helpful.

I recommend that you mail one of the authors of this package if you need further help.